# Using Regex to replace string for converting ltr padding to rtl

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I'm using this Regex:

```
padding:(\s*(\d+px\s*|0\s*)){4}
```

to find padding style's with four values in Visual Studio "Find And Replace".
Now I want to replace the second value with fourth like this:

```
padding: 1px 0 3px 4px;
padding: 1px 2px 0 4px;
padding: 1px 2px 3px 0;
```

change this values to:

```
padding: 1px 4px 3px 0;
padding: 1px 4px 0 2px;
padding: 1px 0 3px 2px;
```

is there a way I can replace them with the "Find And Replace" dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `(\s*(\d+px\s*|0\s*)){4}` captures the `(\s*(\d+px\s*|0\s*))` subpattern 4 times, and the captures are stored in the `CaptureCollection` that can only be retrieved with .NET code. In a search and replace feature, you can only access *groups* with *backreferences*.

You can use:

Find:   `(padding:\s*)(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?);`

Replace: `$1$2 $5 $4 $3`

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(padding%3a%5cs*)(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%5cs*(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%5cs*(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%5cs*(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%3b&i=padding%3a+1px+0+3px+4px%3b%0d%0apadding%3a+1px+2px+0+4px%3b%0d%0apadding%3a+1px+2px+3px+0%3b&r=%241%242+%245+%244+%243)

Results:

```
padding: 1px 4px 3px 0
​padding: 1px 4px 0 2px
​padding: 1px 0 3px 2px
```

Note I decided to hard-code the whitespaces in the replacement, but you can also set capturing groups round `\s*` to replicate them in the resulting string.

Regex breakdown:

- `(padding:\s*)` - Group 1 matching `padding:` plus 0 or more whitespace
- `(\d+(?:px)?)` - Group 2 matching 1 or more digits (`\d+`) and *optionally* `px`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?)` - 3 more capturing groups with indices 3, 4, 5
- `;` - a literal semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you very much stribizhev. I think i can use this approach in two step for replacing "padding: 1px 3px 2px" with "padding: 1px 0 2px 3px", right? or it can be performed in one step?

Comment: The problem is that you need to replace with different replacements patterns. It is not supported in general. Some languages allow replacing with arrays (in PHP, R), but definitely not inside a find-and-replace tool. You can use [`(padding:\s*)(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?)\s*(\d+(?:px)?);`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(padding%3a%5cs*)(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%5cs*(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%5cs*(%5cd%2b(%3f%3apx)%3f)%3b&i=padding%3a+0+2px+4px%3b&r=%241%242+0+%244+%243) and replace with `$1$2 0 $4 $3`.